# teradata studio sorted export using Fastexport

Tags: teradata, fastexport

Is it possible to export data from Teradata Studio in a sorted order using Fastexport?

We are using Teradata Studio version 16.10.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you can just specify an ORDER BY in your select statement and it should do exactly what you like.

Comment: how to do that in Teradata Studio though

Answer (score 0):

I have now concluded that you cannot really modify this in Teradata Studio (but obviously create a Fastexport script in which you order by and then just invoke it from fexp)